# Hibernate one-to-one mapping on same table

Tags: hibernate, mapping, parent, one-to-one

We have a scenario where there is a main product and another sub-product which behaves in exact same manner as main product. Main product can have maximum one sub-product. Whenever user selects main product, we will show user sub-product if available. I have designed it such a way like

```
    public class Product  {
...
    private Product parentProduct;
```

and in hibernate mapping xml (yes..we still using xml)

```
    <one-to-one name="parentProduct" class="uk.co.xxx.domain.Product" cascade="save-update" foreign-key="PARENT_PRODUCT_ID"/>
```

For main products parentProduct will be null.

I am not sure weather one-to-one like this works. Not tried to save product yet.

Do you have any suggestions for such a design? I see some potential faults like sub-product shares many of the attributes of main-product and there is a duplication of code and potential bugs when product itself is created. But by avoiding separate table for sub-product I avoid changes in existing code of reporting, batch etc which uses product table.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. You could set properties shared with parent in copy constructor (when creating sub product, pass parent product as constructor parameter, copy what is needed, set parent as `parentProduct`).

Alternative could be that `SubProduct extends Product`, but you use `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance strategy, not `TABLE_PER_CLASS`. You'd only have to add `dtype` column (plus the foreign key column, which you already have) to `Product` table, so you know which products are main and which aren't. And you'd need to update the values for `dtype`, if you already have existing data.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I need of a bidirection one-to-one relationship avoiding to change the DB's design. I want to save the relation of product and sub-product (of the same type and with 80% of data shared) in the same table. I choose to represent this relationship with a many-to-one with unique constraint (same of one-to-one).

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.my.package" >
<class name="Product" table="PRODUCT" >
    <!-- Class Cache -->
    <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/> 
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="ID" precision="12" scale="0" />
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">PRODUCT_SEQ</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    ...
    <many-to-one name="parentProduct" not-null="true" foreign-key="ID" class="com.my.package.Product" column="PARENT_PRODUCT_ID" cascade="save-update" unique="true" fetch="select" />
    ...
</class>
```

This solution is rather good but not bidirectional relationship. I mean is simple to find the parent from the child but not the inverse.

```
Order.List<Products>
Product_1 -> null 
Product_2 -> Product_1 
...
```

Is there something to do for knowing if Product_1 has a child instead of execute each times java cicles for checking the whole productsList?

I hope this solution helps you somehow although not complete.